# Where can I find out more about the process of tag cleanup on a Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

What is the methodology used to clean up tags on a Stack Exchange site?

I'm interested to know the process that goes into this for my own purposes when I create a wiki on a specific topic.

I'm pretty certain that the process has something to do with identifying and then combining  synonyms, and splitting too generalized tags into multiple tags.

Also how are tags that refer to *singular* or *plural* handled, for instance [server](/questions/tagged/server) or [servers](/questions/tagged/servers) ?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135985/182741) is a *work in progress* cleanup.